# What is the difference between Mapreduce and Filter with sum in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia version: 1.4.0

I have these two snippets, I think they should be equivalent but they produce very different results. What am I missing?

samples is `Vector{Float64}` with 1000000 elements. Moreover, it's a random sampling of a posterior distribution.

```
mapreduce(p -> p < 0.5 ? 1 : 0, +, samples) / N

sum(filter(x-> x<0.5, samples))/N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapreduce` is `map`ping each element to either `1` or `0`.  Instead, you want to map each element to either `p` or `0`.

```
julia> N = 1000000;

julia> samples = randn(1000000);

julia> mapreduce(p -> p < 0.5 ? 1 : 0, +, samples) / N
0.690901

julia> mapreduce(p -> p < 0.5 ? p : -0.0, +, samples) / N
-0.35058272143615

julia> sum(filter(x-> x<0.5, samples))/N
-0.35058272143615005
```

These may still see a very very slight difference (in this case it's just 1 unit-in-the-last-place) because the results will depend upon the order of summation.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't quite understood yet. What is ´´´?´´´ and how do you use it ?

Comment: That's the [ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#man-conditional-evaluation-1).